# Better way to store XdmValue in the database as XmlType using saxon.

Tags: java, oracle, saxon, xmltype

I am executing XQuery using Saxon 9API. The result of XQuery is returned as net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmValue.I am constructing DOM document object from this XdmValue. I am pasting the code below.

```
    Processor saxon = new Processor(false);
    saxon.registerExtensionFunction(new MyExtension());

    XQueryCompiler compiler = saxon.newXQueryCompiler();
    XQueryExecutable exec = compiler.compile(new File("input/studentXQuery.xq"));
    XQueryEvaluator query = exec.load();


    String students = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><student_list><student><name>George Washington</name><major>Politics</major><phone>312-123-4567</phone><email>gw@example.edu</email></student><student><name>Janet Jones</name><major>Undeclared</major><phone>311-122-2233</phone><email>janetj@example.edu</email></student><student><name>Joe Taylor</name><major>Engineering</major><phone>211-111-2333</phone><email>joe@example.edu</email></student></student_list>";
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(students));
    Document doc1 = db.parse(is);


    DocumentBuilder builder = saxon.newDocumentBuilder();
    Source src = new DOMSource(doc1);
    XdmNode doc = builder.build(src);
    query.setExternalVariable(new QName("student_list"), doc);

    XdmValue result = query.evaluate();

    System.out.println("Result is -------- "+result.toString());
    InputSource is1 = new InputSource();
    is1.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(result.toString()));
    Document resultDoc = db.parse(is1);
    System.out.println("Result doc is "+resultDoc);
```

My question is what is the better way to store this output as XmlType in Oracle DB. Is the DOM document construction is required to avoid handling strings to hold xml values? Or Is it good way to construct XmlType on top of the String itself. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a DOM as an intermediate form seems pretty clunky. I suspect it's just as easy/fast to serialize the Saxon result and reparse it from a string - but I don't know what options Oracle offers.

Comment: Converting XDMValue to a String and parsing it as an Oracle XMLType will be an expensive operation (performance) compared to retrieving the DOM object and using it to build the Oracle XMLType. I assume both Oracle and Saxon will use optimizations if DOM is supplied as apposed to String. Is there a way to pull out DOM in the above example. Please note that performance in both the approaches will be evaluated..

Comment: I will be interested to see your measurements. Generally, the DOM is slow, and almost anything else is usually preferable.